# Both \n and \r\n get the same result in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I have set android:defaultValue="\n", but when I open the PreferenceScreen, I find the third item  is selected, I think the first item should be selected.

And more, I find more surprising thing. even if I select the third item, but the value String newLineValue = prefs.getString("SetNewLine", "\n") is "\n", it should be "\r\n".

Why? Thanks!

```
private String GetNewLine(){  
  SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
  String newLineValue = prefs.getString("SetNewLine", "\n");  
  if (newLineValue.equals("\n")){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  return newLineValue;
}
```

**array.xml**

```
   <string-array name="NewLine">
        <item>Make new line with \\n</item>
        <item>Make new line with &lt;br/&gt;</item>
        <item>Make new line with \\r\\n</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="NewLine_values">
        <item>\n</item>
        <item>&lt;br/&gt;</item>
        <item>\r\n</item>
    </string-array>
```

**mypreference.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="AppPreference"
    android:summary="@string/Preferencesummary"
    android:title="@string/Preference" >


    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="\n"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/NewLineFormat"
        android:entries="@array/NewLine"
        android:entryValues="@array/NewLine_values"
        android:key="SetNewLine"
        android:summary="@string/NewLineFormatsummary"
        android:title="@string/NewLineFormat"
        android:layout="@layout/mypreference_layout" 
        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Looks like something is normalizing newlines either by mistake or because it looked like a good idea in some other case. You might have to work around it by storing some token value and do further conversion in your code.

Comment: I have do some test, the second item is OK, but system don't judge the first item and the third item, I don't know why.